# Executing Bash commands using C code

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I'm trying to use `file.cpp` to execute some simple `bash` commands. Code works for commands like `ls`, `gedit`, `echo` but fails at `cd` command.

Here is my file.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char *cd[] = {
        "/bin/bash",
        "-c",
        "cd /etc",
        NULL
    };
    execvp(cd[0], cd);
    return 0;
}
```

I execute it after compiling using `./file` and my terminal output is,

```
rahul@Inspiron:~/Desktop$ g++ -Wno-write-strings file.cpp -o file
rahul@Inspiron:~/Desktop$ ./file 
rahul@Inspiron:~/Desktop$
```

Current directory didn't change to `/etc`. I have tried changing  `cd /etc` to `cd ..`, `cd some_directory` in `file.cpp` but no success.

Please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `exec` type commands usually run in their own environment. As in, they won't affect anything else, like the process you called them from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own current directory.

When you run `/bin/bash -c "cd /etc"` Bash starts up, changes its current directory, then exits. This happens regardless of whether you run it with `exec`, or `fork` then `exec`, or `system`, or by typing it into a shell, or some other way.

It has no effect on the current directory of the shell you ran it from.

Comment: So Is there a way to see those changes in current terminal session?

Comment: @Rahul No there is not.

Comment: no - because there are no changes to the current session. You cannot do what you are trying to do. `cd` is a command built in to the shell, its not a program (vs `ls` or `mkdir`)

Comment: @pm100  Suppose I want to execute a command in some other directory then this C code method won't work?

Comment: @immibis Thanks that helps.

Comment: @Rahul actualy if you want to execute code in another directory you can, just put the full path in the exec - instead of '-c foo` say `-c \home\joe\foo`

Comment: @rahul: [`man 2 chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)

Comment: @rici Thanks man, `chdir` worked. I used it as `chdir("~/Desktop");
 execlp("ls", "ls", "-ltr", (char *)0);` and it showed me file in `Desktop` folder

Comment: @rici Maybe you should write an answer it may help others also.